# Store the indexes of random elements correctly in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, indexof

I got an array `a` which is filled by node objects. For example I got 200 nodes on my screen and all are saved inside this array. These nodes are labeled by individual indexes `a[0], a[1],` ect. Now, when I select a number of random nodes (for example with shortest path) and store them in a second array `b` which looks like `b = [ object, object, object, object.....]`,
 is there a way to automatically return the position in array `a`? For example, when I click a random node, which is at the 3rd position in array `a` , that means at `a[2]`, then I want that this position is returned or stored automatically, maybe in a third array `c`. And at the end, it could look like: `c= [ a[2], a[6], a[18], a[7], a[0]  .....]`. Hope someone can help me with my problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: How do you get `b`?

Comment: hey, i use a d3.js method to return the shortest path. But when i `console.log(b)`, it says `[ object, object, object, object.....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your array `a` looks like this :

```
a = [{id:1} , {id:2} , {id:3} , {id:4}]
```

and then you randomly click on elements, so that they are then stored in an array `b` as such :

```
b = [{id:3}, {id:1}]
```

So eventually you want to memorize the information that a[2] is stored in position b[0], and a[0] is stored in position b[1], right?

What you could do is not store the entire objects in `b`, but just their id :

```
b = [3, 1]
```

This way, you can easily find what position they're at :

```
findPosition(node){
 return b.indexOf( node.id )
}

console.log(findPosition(a[2])) // 0
```

Comment: Hey, my array looks like this `a = [ object, object, object, object.....]`. But each object has an index.

Comment: Yeah so? Looks like it fits what I suggested, doesn't it? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the format of your arrays and what the objects contain. Using indexOf, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf, may be a solution.

Using indexOf you can search the first array using the object that is clicked in the second array, you could then push this to a third array.